# "WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH" error while 'driver = webdriver.Firefox()' through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

To the experts out there, I ran the following code in Python using Spyder (on Mac):

```
>from selenium import webdriver
>from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
>driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and I get the following errors:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>
>  File "<ipython-input-4-fd567e24185f>", line 1, in <module>
>    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
>
>  File "/Users/liminfang/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site->packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 160, in __init__
>    self.service.start()
>
>  File "/Users/liminfang/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site->packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
>    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>
>WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Note that I have already added 'geckodriver' executable to the PATH by executing

```
>export PATH=$PATH:/Users/liminfang/anaconda3/geckodriver
```

in Terminal. And I restarted my computer, but the error persists. Anyone know what's going on here? Please help. Thank you!

Comment: think you're missing .exe from the path i.e. geckodriver.exe

Comment: @Limin if my answer solved your issue, please mark it as **accept**

Comment: @SimonN the geckodriver is a folder. I put the executable file in that folder. Because I am using a mac, there is no extension .exe for it.

Comment: @M. Khajavi  I am using a Mac OS 10.13.4. So I am not sure if your solution will work yet. Will try tomorrow on my PC and get back to you. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `geckodriver.exe` in the **script folder** and then call `webdriver.Firefox` with:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, firefox_profile=fp, executable_path='geckodriver.exe')
```

I've 52.0.2 (64 bit) and Geckodriver 0.15.0-win64 and it's working!

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was not found within the directories you have mentioned within your `PATH` variable.

### Solution

As you are using **ipython** you can download the latest *GeckoDriver* from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and place it anywhere within your system. While initializing the new *WebDriver*/*WebClient* session pass the *absolute* path of the *GeckoDriver* binary through the **executable_path** argument as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
```

Comment: I tried your solution, still get a very long error message. I can't post it here because it is too long. Note that I am using Mac.

Comment: The problem is with ipython. If I ran the script in Terminal directly, everything works.